# How to take data from array? Can't take data in const from array

Tags: reactjs

[This is data array protocols](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acebc.png)

https://dropmefiles.com/MchK8 this is my code.
Why selectMembers is empty and when I directly do the protocol.Members, it issues data?
How can i use Selectedmembers?

```
componentDidMount() {
        const {members} = this.props;
        const selectedMembers = [];
        this.getProtocolsDetails(this.props.protocol.id);
        this.setState({isLoading: true});
        console.log(protocol);
        // if (!isNull(protocol.members) && protocol.members.length) {
        //  protocol.members.map(member => {
        //      selectedMembers.push({
        //          label: member.fullName,
        //          value: member.code
        //      });
        //  });
        // }
}

getProtocolsDetails(id) {
    ProtoApi.getProtocolById(id)
        .then(protocol => {
            this.setState({protocol}, () => {
            });
        })
        .catch(() => {
        });
}
<AutoComplete label="Участники"
    placeholder="Выберите участников"
    searchApi={this.onSearchMembers}
    onUpdate={this.onChooseMember}
    onDeleteItem={this.onDeleteMember}
    multiple={true}
    dataSource={selectedMembers}
    error={!isUndefined(errors.members)}
    helperText={!isUndefined(errors.members) ? errors.members : null}/>
```

I want to take and show data when i edit this element members in selectedMembers from array looks like empty but it show like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vH1Hu.png) if i have doesnt empty `selectedMembers`

Comment: Hi Welcome to SO. Please don’t add links/images that refers to your code. The code which you have shared in that link contains a lot and lot of code and it’s very difficult to identify where exactly you are pointing to so please add specific/relevant code regarding the issue in the question itself with detailed issue description

Comment: Sorry please w8 a min

Answer (score 0):

The first after request you save data in `this.state.protocol`, but display in `console.log` just `protocol`.

The second `componentDidMount` will not wait api response, you should use `componentDidUpdate` or replace logic in `getProtocolsDetails`